# Sympy derivative with a non-symbol

Tags: sympy

For a project i am working on i need the derivative of a function against wrt cos(theta) but when using Sympy v1.5.1 get an error message stating non-symbols cannot be used as a derivative. This was no problem up to Sympy v1.3 but later versions give this error.

```
>>> l=1
>>> theta = symbols('theta')
>>> eq=diff((cos(theta)**2-1)**l,cos(theta),l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live- 
hrd/20200105t193609.423659059328302322/sympy/sympy/core/function.py", line 2446, in diff
return f.diff(*symbols, **kwargs)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live- 
hrd/20200105t193609.423659059328302322/sympy/sympy/core/expr.py", line 3352, in diff
return Derivative(self, *symbols, **assumptions)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live- 
hrd/20200105t193609.423659059328302322/sympy/sympy/core/function.py", line 1343, in __new__
__)))
ValueError: 
Can't calculate derivative wrt cos(theta).
```

According to the Sympy documentation (https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.function.Derivative) i may be able to solve this using:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import t
>>> F = Function('F')
>>> U = f(t)
>>> V = U.diff(t)
>>> direct = F(t, U, V).diff(U)
```

Unfortunately i can't get this to work with this equation in Sympy v1.5.1. 
Suggestions/help are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> derivative of a function against wrt cos(theta)

Did this really work before in sympy? i.e. you were able to differentiate w.r.t `cos(theta)`? This should not work as differentiation is w.r.t to a symbol. For example Maple also gives error

```
diff( 1+cos(theta)^2,cos(theta))
Error, invalid input: diff received cos(theta), which is not valid for its 2nd argument
```

Strange that Mathematica does allow this. But I think this is not good behavior. May be that is why sympy no longer allows it.

But you can do this in sympy

```
from sympy import *
theta,x = symbols('theta x')
eq      = (cos(theta)**2-1)**2

result  = diff( eq.subs(cos(theta),x) ,x)

result.subs(x,cos(theta))
```

Which gives

```
 4*(cos(theta)**2 - 1)*cos(theta)
```

In Mathematica (which allows this)

```
 D[(Cos[theta]^2 - 1)^2, Cos[theta]]
```

gives

```
 4 Cos[theta] (-1 + Cos[theta]^2)
```

Comment: Many thanks Nasser. This indeed should work. Fyi on this web page https://github.com/damontallen/Orbitals/blob/master/Hydrogen%20Orbitals%20(Feb%2018,%202014)%20(dynamic%20entry).ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps SymPy over-corrected. If the expression has a single generator matching the function of interest then the substitution-equivalent differentiation could take place. Cases which shouldn't (probably) be allowed are `(x + 1).diff(cos(x))`, `sin(x).diff(cos(x))`, etc... But `(cos(x)**2 - 1).diff(cos(x))` should (probably) be ok. As @Nasser has indicated, a simple substitution/differentiation/backsubstitution will work.

Comment: I think it's better to be explicit about this. Otherwise there is always ambiguity about what is really meant, even in that case. If you really want `expr.subs(cos(theta), x).diff(x).subs(x, cos(theta)`, then that's what you should write.